# Get for each iteration the biggest value

Tags: c++

I have a `cv::Mat mat`, do some stuff with it and get a `std::vector<cv::Points> diagonalPoints` for further coding and here it gets tricky - After creating those `diagonalPoints` I go through each column to get the maximum distance between two points (for each column, therefore I compare `[i].x`and `[i+1].x` - see below). But (!) after computing that I'll get **each** `maxDist` for a column, which is biiger than the prevoius, not the *biggest one for a column*.

Here's the essential part of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < diagonalPoints.size(); i++) {
    int dist = diagonalPoints[i + 1].y - diagonalPoints[i].y;

    if (diagonalPoints[i].x == diagonalPoints[i + 1].x) {
        if (dist > maxDist) {
            maxDist = dist;
            maxDistColumn = diagonalPoints[i].x;
            firstPt = diagonalPoints[i];
            secondPt = diagonalPoints[i + 1];
        }
    }
    else if (diagonalPoints[i].x != diagonalPoints[i + 1].x) {
        maxDist = 0;
    }
    std::cout << maxDist << " in i: " << maxDistColumn << "\n";
    farestPoints = std::make_pair(firstPt, secondPt);
    std::cout << farestPoints.first << ", " << farestPoints.second << " ";
}
```

The output is (to reduce it, just for the first column):

```
[0, 26], [0, 39] - maxDist: 13 in i: 0
[0, 26], [0, 39] - maxDist: 13 in i: 0
[0, 26], [0, 39] - maxDist: 13 in i: 0
[0, 42], [0, 950] - maxDist: 908 in i: 0
[0, 42], [0, 950] - maxDist: 908 in i: 0
[0, 42], [0, 950] - maxDist: 908 in i: 0
```

But I just would like to get only `[0, 42], [0, 950] - maxDist: 908 in i: 0` because it is the biggest value. Surely it could be just a simple change in my code, but I really don't get it. What should I change?

Thanks!

Comment: Move the printing outside the loop and only capture the max in the loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver if so, it prints just the last iteration.

Comment: before setting `maxDist`, you could compare to its previous value. Only set if it is higher. then print it outside `for` loop

Comment: @Nipun how can I get all the previous `dist`s?

Comment: It is already handled in your code by `(dist > maxDist)`, output is in ascending order. As NathanOliver mentioned above, you don't need to print in loop, print outside loop.

Comment: Your `else ... { maxDist = 0; }` looks suspect. Why do you have that?

Comment: @Nipun but than I'll get only the last output?

Comment: @Caleth to make sure computing the distance for the same column

Comment: I believe you need to debug your code and try to understand what you have written. You check `(dist > maxDist)` will ensure you always have highest one. `maxDist = 0;` in `else` may disrupt desired behavior, this needs to be controlled

Comment: @Nipun already done - if `maxDist` is bigger than `dist`, it will be returned. But than there is probably a higher value than the value, which was computed before. So I need only *this* bigger value.

Comment: @Nipun if the debugger finds a higher value, it do not look/compare anymore at/to the previous (at that moment biggest). If you look at my output in the question, after `13` it goes back to the `if` case and ignores the comparison of the new calculated `maxDist` `908` to the last one `13`. That's the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to move the printing to when you have found the end of a column.

```
for (int i = 0; i < diagonalPoints.size() - 1 /* need to stop before going off the end */; i++) {
    if (diagonalPoints[i].x == diagonalPoints[i + 1].x) {
        // same column, so calculate distance and compare
        int dist = diagonalPoints[i + 1].y - diagonalPoints[i].y;
        if (dist > maxDist) {
            maxDist = dist;
            maxDistColumn = diagonalPoints[i].x;
            firstPt = diagonalPoints[i];
            secondPt = diagonalPoints[i + 1];
        }
    }
    else {
        // new column, so print the maximum and reset
        std::cout << maxDist << " in i: " << maxDistColumn << "\n";
        farestPoints = std::make_pair(firstPt, secondPt);
        std::cout << farestPoints.first << ", " << farestPoints.second << " ";
        maxDist = 0;
    }
}

// after the loop, we still have the last column to print
std::cout << maxDist << " in i: " << maxDistColumn << "\n";
farestPoints = std::make_pair(firstPt, secondPt);
std::cout << farestPoints.first << ", " << farestPoints.second << "
```

Comment: Thank you, works flawless! Didn't really get it, to put it in the `else`-part.